# How to render the radio buttons without ul in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

#### forms.py

```
Date_Format = (
    ('0', ' dd / mm / yyyy'),
    ('1', 'mm / dd / yyyy'),
)    
Time_Format = (
    ('0', ' 12 hour AM / PM '),
    ('1', ' 24 hour '),
)
class SettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date_format = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=Date_Format)
    time_format = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=Time_Format)
```

#### template.py

Update:

```
                    {% for radio in SettingsForm.date_format %}
                    {{ radio.choice_label }}
                    <div class="select">{{ radio.tag }}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

The above form is rendering the radio buttons in a unordered list, but I want to be with out unordered list. How can I perform this?

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect) states, you can iterate the choices in a template (see karthikr's answer) or create your own widget or widget render method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over the `RadioSelect` in the template

```
{% for choice in form.date_format %}
  {{ choice.choice_label }}
  <div class="select">{{ choice.tag }}</div> {# Or any other type you want. #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I am using modelForm,radio button is not rendering in html.After customization no fields are dispalyed

Comment: can you share your template?

Comment: This looks fine. It should work - see this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.RadioSelect . Can you restart the server?

Comment: In template,i misspelled the SettingsForm as settingsForm so their is no changes,but i changed and tried i am getting this error"Caught TypeError while rendering: 'BoundField' object is not iterable"

Comment: Did you try the other approach ??

Comment: Not tried,but if i put the form name i am getting this error "Caught TypeError while rendering: 'BoundField' object is not iterable"

Comment: You code looks fine. Guess you are doing something very trivial wrong here.

Answer (score 17):

You could create a custom renderer:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms.widgets import RadioFieldRenderer
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils.html import format_html_join
from django.utils.encoding import force_text


class RadioFieldWithoutULRenderer(RadioFieldRenderer):

    def render(self):
        return format_html_join(
            '\n',
            '<li>{0}</li>',
            [(force_text(w), ) for w in self],
        )


CHOICES = (
    ('0', ' 12 hour AM / PM '),
    ('1', ' 24 hour '),
)


class MyForm(forms.Form):
    somefield = forms.ChoiceField(
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=RadioFieldWithoutULRenderer),
        choices=CHOICES)


def myview(request):
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': MyForm()})
```

Comment: Is it possible to customize models form like this

Comment: Yes you can inherit `forms.ModelForm` instead

Comment: RadioFieldRenderer was removed in later versions of Django, so this will no longer work. Here's a link to discussion on how to route around this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46517799/choicefieldrenderer-removed-what-is-the-solution