# Render radio buttons without UL in Django 1.11

Tags: django

I need to render a radio button group without UL.  In Django 1.9, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16523287/2233706), and I use this in many places.  I'm upgrading to Django 1.11, and `RadioFieldRenderer` is [no longer supported](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.11/#changes-due-to-the-introduction-of-template-based-widget-rendering).  How can I accomplish what I'm doing right now in Django 1.11?

**This is what I ended up doing in my template as per dirkgroten's answer**

```
{% with id=widget.attrs.id %}
{% for group, options, index in widget.optgroups %}
    {% for option in options %}
        {% include option.template_name with widget=option %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Django 1.11, the way widgets are defined has changed a lot. But it makes it easier to customise. The `RadioSelect` widget uses the `multiple_input.html` template. Your best option to remove the `<ul>` is to do the following:

- Subclass `RadioSelect` to use your own template:

  ```
  class MyRadioSelect(RadioSelect):
      template_name = 'my_widgets/radio.html'
  ```
- Copy the `multiple_input.html` (that's the standard django template) code into your own template ("*my_widgets/radio.html*") and adjust everything the way you want it. You can use `<div>`s instead of `<ul>` and `<li>` or whatever you want.
- In your form, use your own widget:

  ```
  options = ChoiceField(widget=MyRadioSelect)
  ```

Comment: Thanks, there's so much stuff that changed in Django 1.11.  By the way, the code for [multiple_input.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11.4/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/multiple_input.html) was difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have a `form.py`, where you store your forms.

In the respective form and field that you want to render as radio buttons, make it like this:

```
choices_field = forms.ChoiceField(
    widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'some-class-here'})
)
```

The important thing is to use the `RadioSelect` widget, either in a `ChoiceField`, `ModelChoiceField` etc.