# ChoiceFieldRenderer removed. What is the solution?

Tags: python, django

It seems very few people used it, but... I did. [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.11/#deprecated-features-1-11) you can read:

> Some undocumented classes in django.forms.widgets are removed:
>   SubWidget RendererMixin, ChoiceFieldRenderer, RadioFieldRenderer,
>   CheckboxFieldRenderer ChoiceInput, RadioChoiceInput,
>   CheckboxChoiceInput

My source code is:

```
from django.forms.widgets import ChoiceFieldRenderer, RadioChoiceInput, \
    RendererMixin, Select


class BootstrapRadioFieldRenderer(ChoiceFieldRenderer):
    outer_html = '<span {id_attr}>{content}</span>'
    inner_html = '<div class="radio">{choice_value}{sub_widgets}</div>'
    choice_input_class = RadioChoiceInput


class BootstrapRadioSelect(RendererMixin, Select):
    renderer = BootstrapRadioFieldRenderer
    _empty_value = ''
```

I really dont know how to convert this to make it work with 1.11 and later: they say:

```
Use a custom widget template instead.
```

Well. How?

Comment: Have you found a workaround since?

Comment: Nope **`:^/`** I'll have to search by myself when I have some time, but it feels like we are the only ones who used this method...

Comment: I can soon show you a version of me getting around losing `RadioFieldRenderer`. But I can already share that not setting `FORM_RENDERER` to `django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting` was a huge waste of time. It otherwise will not search for templates like views do ><

Comment: Waiting eagerly for your answer `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We used RadioFieldRenderer to add a description to each option. Your usecase may be far from it, but I hope it helps you to make the migration too.

This was the legacy code for Django <=1.10

```
class MyRadioFieldRenderer(forms.widgets.RadioFieldRenderer):

    def render(self):
        radios = []
        for w in self:
            radios.append(u"""<li class="%s">%s <span>%s</span></li>"""
                          % (w.choice_value, force_unicode(w), get_description(w)))
        return mark_safe(u'<ul>\n%s\n</ul>' % u'\n'.join(radios))

class MyRadioSelect(forms.RadioSelect):
    renderer = MyRadioFieldRenderer
```

And I replaced it with this for Django 1.11 utilizing custom template snippets and only adding the description to the template context.

```
from django.forms.widgets import RadioSelect

class MyRadioSelect(RadioSelect):

    template_name = 'myapp/multiple_input.html'
    option_template_name = 'myapp/input_option.html'

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super(MyRadioSelect, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)

        for i in range(len(context['widget']['optgroups'][0][1])):
            value = context['widget']['optgroups'][0][1][i]['value']
            context['widget']['optgroups'][0][1][i]['attrs']['description'] = \
                get_description(value)
        return context
```

*The for loop in this deep list is not pretty. Need to look at that again.*

In the template snippet I can then render the description behind the options with `<span>{{widget.attrs.description | safe}}</span>`

The form remained the same:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    order_method = ChoiceField(
        widget=MyRadioSelect,
        required=True)
```

---

***Important: For Django to find your custom template snippets in the regular template folder add this to your settings:***

```
FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
```

and `django.forms` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`